# Does it take longer time to load web page with failed images

Tags: html, image

I have a webpage that will shows table of **1500** records with image in each record. I've saved the image name as [row_id].png. 
So i can easily assign the image src as [row_id]

I have used  `onerror='imgError(this);'` for assigning default image if real image is not available. Although, around **1400** errors are shown in firebug `( Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found))`

However, my concern here is whether it takes longer time if I specify image src which does not exist?

Comment: Longer than if you did what alternative?

Comment: Are you showing 1500 in one page? Is there any pagination?

Comment: @ArinCool, yes, pagination is done

Comment: @Quentin, Longer than if I change the logic and set null in image name if image is not saved. And while displaying I will load the image only if image name is not null.. but I am wondering if its worth giving such efforts? will that make any difference at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most time consuming things you can do on the WWW is to make an HTTP request.

You are trying to load 1400 different images which don't exist. Each one of those requires an HTTP request.

Changing your logic so you don't try to include an image at all will be significantly faster.